# Optimize loop for changepoint test

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I'm trying to write a simple change point finder in Python.  Below, the function loglike(xs) returns the maximized log-likelihood for an iid normal sample xs.  The function most_probable_cp(xs) loops through each point in the middle ~75% of xs, and uses a likelihood ratio to find the most likely change point in xs.

I'm using binary segmentation, and I'm bootstrapping to get critical values for the likelihood ratio, so I'll need to call most_probable_cp() thousands of times.  Is there any way to speed it up?  Would Cython help at all?  I've never used it.

```
import numpy as np

def loglike(xs):
    n = len(xs)
    mean = np.sum(xs)/n
    sigSq = np.sum((xs - mean)**2)/n
    return -0.5*n*np.log(2*np.pi*sigSq) - 0.5*n


def most_probable_cp(xs, left=None, right=None):
    """
    Finds the most probable changepoint location and corresponding likelihood for xs[left:right]
    """
    if left is None:
        left = 0

    if right is None:
        right = len(xs)

    OFFSETPCT = 0.125
    MINNOBS = 12

    ys = xs[left:right]
    offset = min(int(len(ys)*OFFSETPCT), MINNOBS)
    tLeft, tRight = left + offset, right - offset
    if tRight <= tLeft:
        raise ValueError("left and right are too close together.")

    maxLike = -1e9
    cp = None
    dataLike = loglike(ys)
    # Bottleneck is below.
    for t in xrange(tLeft, tRight):
        profLike = loglike(xs[left:t]) + loglike(xs[t:right])
        lr = 2*(profLike - dataLike)
        if lr > maxLike:
            cp = t
            maxLike = lr

    return cp, maxLike
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing, use Numpy's implementation of standard deviation. That will not only be faster, but also more stable.

```
def loglike(xs):
    n = len(xs)
    return -0.5 * n * np.log(2 * np.pi * np.std(xs)) - 0.5 * n
```

If you really want to squeeze miliseconds, you could use bottleneck's `nanstd` function instead, because it is faster. And if you want to scrap microseconds, you could replace `np.log` by `math.log`, as you are only operating on a single number, and if `xs` is an array, you can use `xs.std()` instead. But before going down that road, I advise you to use this version, and profile the results to see where time is being spent.

**Edit**

If you profile loglike `python -m cProfile -o output yourprogram.py; runsnake output`, you will see that most (around 80%) of the time is being spent computing `np.std`. That is our first target. As I said before, the best call is to use `bottleneck.nanstd`.

```
import bottleneck as bn

def loglike(xs):
    n = len(xs)
    return -0.5 * n * np.log(2 * np.pi * bn.nanstd(xs)) - 0.5 * n
```

In my benchmark, it makes a speedup of 8x, and it is only a 30% of the time. `len` is a 5%, so no point in looking into it further. Replacing np.log and np.pi by their math counterparts, and taking common factor I can cut the time in half again.

```
return -0.5 * n * (math.log(2 * math.pi * bn.nanstd(xs)) - 1)
```

I can yet sqeeze an aditional 10% hurting readability a bit:

```
factor = math.log(2*math.pi)

def loglike(xs):
    n = len(xs)
    return -0.5 * n * (factor + math.log(bn.nanstd(xs)) - 1)
```

**Edit 2**

If you want to really push it, you can replace bn.nanstd for the specialized function. Before your loop, define `std, _ = bn.func.nansum_selector(xs, axis=0)` and use it instead of bn.nanstd, or just `func.nanstd_1d_float64_axisNone` if you are not going to change the dtype.

And I think this is as fast as it gets in Python. Still, half of the time is being spent on number operations, and perhaps Cython would be able to optimise this, but then calling in and out of Python would add an overhead that could compensate for this.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried replacing the functions, and it didn't help much.  I'm hoping for at least a 10x speed up.

Comment: Where is your time being spent? We could stare at your code looking for possible bottlenecks until our eyes hurt and still miss them. Do you know how to do profiling?

Comment: Sorry.  Should've been clearer: 90% of the time is in the line profLike = loglike(xs[left:t]) + loglike(xs[t:right])

Comment: In my benchmark, I now got a 20x improvement. Hopefully you will get something similar in your real case.

Comment: Of course, if this is still a significant bottleneck, you could try to go parallel.

Comment: You need to profile, as well as realize that each call to np.sum and the array operations are implicit loops. These are likely eating most of your time. I've added an answer that might help asymptotically; this answer still keeps the essentially quadratic performance intact.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic changes I would make: currently, you recalculate the sum of squares, mean, and count for each partition on every iteration, which makes this "cross-validation style" algorithm quadratic.

What you can do is exploit the semigroup structure and calculate the squared values of each element, the count, and the mean in an online fashion as you change the partition -- basically fusing the implicit loops in np.sum. You then take `-0.5*n*np.log(2*np.pi*sigSq) - 0.5*n` and calculate that based on the updated values of n, mean and sigSq (you will need to calculate the stddev from the sum of squared values).

This will asymptotically speed up your code as well as save you some function calls at the potential cost of numeric stability compared with np.std. You might need kahan summation.

If you don't need the actual log likelihood, you can focus on only maximizing `proflike` and then calculating `lr` outside the loop, saving a few multiplies--(you can fold the 2* and the 0.5 * in the functions together if you do some basic algebra regardless)

This technique is the one behind HLearn and its high performance in cross validation.

Edit: some code that will likely be much quicker than the others. The biggest cost here is the iteration overhead and the np.log calls. There might be some fencepost errors but here is the gist:

```py
rcnt = n
rsum = np.sum(arr)
rssq = np.sum(arr**2)
lcnt = 0
lsum = 0
lssq = 0

maxlike = -1e9 # or -Inf ideally
cp = -1

for i in arr: # arr is length n
    lcnt += 1
    lsum += i
    lssq += i*i
    lmean = lsum/lcnt
    lvar = ((lssq - lmean**2)/(lcnt)) 
    loglike_l = lcnt*np.log(2*np.pi*lvar) - lcnt

    rcnt -= 1
    rsum -= i
    rssq -= i*i
    rmean = rsum/rcnt
    rvar = ((rssq - rmean**2)/(rcnt)) 
    loglike_r = rcnt*np.log(2*np.pi*rvar) - rcnt

    loglike_total = loglike_l + loglike_r

    if maxlike < loglike_total:
        cp = lcnt
        maxlike = loglike_total
```

Comment: Great thanks.  After reading your initial post, I was just looking at http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html

Comment: Yeah that would be a better way to update the left hand quantities. The right hand ones would also need to be compensated for as well. Check if you need to before you do, of course.

The point is to get a one-pass algorithm to compute all the relevant quantities, rather than the expensive multipass one you initially wrote

Comment: For numbers, math is faster than numpy. I am concerned about the numerical stability, though.

Comment: To get the full speed, vectorizing may help. You can replace lsum for np.cumsum(arr), lcnt for np.arange(1, n), and lssq for np.cumsum(arr*arr)

Comment: @Davidmh I doubt it; the point is to fuse those 3 loops into 1 and do it "online" 

Of course profiling is the only way to be sure. Using cumsum is much more likely to be numerically stable. A similar thing can be done for the right hand sums -- basically we want all the prefix and suffix sums and then we can optimize over those.